# Show that $\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n^2 - \mu^2) \to 2\mu|\sigma Z$ in distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

(Full disclosure--this is a homework problem.)

Let $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2 < \infty$. I want to show that if $\mu \neq 0$ then
\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n^2 - \mu^2) \to 2 \mu \sigma Z \quad \text{in distribution as } n \to \infty,
\end{align*}
where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable.

*My attempt*. We have
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma} (\overline{X}_n^2 - \mu^2) = \frac{\overline{X}_n^2 - \mu^2}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} = \left(\frac{\overline{X}_n - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \right)\left(\overline{X}_n + \mu \right).
\end{align*}

Now $\frac{\overline{X}_n - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \to Z$ in distribution as $n \to \infty$ by the Central Limit Theorem. And $\overline{X}_n \to \mu$ almost surely by the Strong Law of Large Numbers. Therefore, $\overline{X}_n \to 2\mu$ almost surely, and hence $\overline{X}_n \to 2\mu$ in probability. Then by Slutsky's Theorem,
\begin{align*}
   \left(\frac{\overline{X}_n - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \right)\left(\overline{X}_n + \mu \right) \to 2\mu Z \quad \text{in distribution as } n \to \infty,
\end{align*}
and therefore,
\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n^2 - \mu^2) \to 2\mu \sigma Z \quad \text{in distribution as } n \to \infty.
\end{align*}
How do we get the absolute value sign? I'm not seeing my mistake...

Comment: This can be obtain by an application of the [*delta* method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no mistake. If $Z$ has standard normal distribution and $c$ is a real constant, then $cZ$ and $|c|Z$ have the same distribution.

Comment: Ahh, good point! Thank you :)